# fingerprint not working in Acer Swift 3 SF314-51-73XF

Tags: fingerprint-reader

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Swift 3 SF314-51-73XF. But the fingerprint sensor is not working. I tried fingerprint GUI, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no driver support for it yet and nobody seems have started writing one at the present time from what I know. Same issue on Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

About all you can do is clean the sensor and uninstall the driver from Device Mgr. Then cold boot and let Windows re-detect and re-install the driver.

Regards,
Srinath

Comment: That may work in Windows but not in Ubuntu.